# Very strange visual studio behaviour with excessive lines of whitespace

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, perforce

yesterday we updated to a new version of some middleware we are using, and had a very bizarre merge problem with perforce... it had created approximately 10-20 thousand lines of white space in one of my functions, this all compiled fine, upon running the program it crashed indicating some memory issue, tracing back through the call stack I discovered visual studio was pointing the debugger right into the middle of the function that had the thousands of lines of white space in it, deleting the excess lines and recompiling fixed this issue, I was just wondering how this is so?, there was no difference in the code and the compiler is supposed to ignore all white space, is this some kind of bug in visual studio?

thanks

Comment: It's a shame you (I assume) can't post a diff.  Yes, C++ whitespace is supposed to be insignificant almost everywhere.

Comment: unfortunately cant post a dif of the source code, but could probably post the space inbetween braces with the specifics of the function it was in modified if thats any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it's white space and not [Whitespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_(programming_language))?